# How to fix broken bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I broke my bash - but it is unclear how I did it.

I tried to enable vi inside the terminal by using `set -o vi`, but not only did it not work, it seems like it broke it completely.

Now half of my commands do not show output, and the keys are not working as expected.

For instance - if I type something

```
$ some command
```

and press `Delete`, then I expect nothing to happen (cursor at the end of the line) - but the prompt changes to:

```
(arg: 3) some command
```

The only way to fix this behavior seems to be running the following command

```
set -o emacs
```

However even setting this in ~/.bashrc does not work, I need to run it in each terminal... 
I am looking for a way to either:
1. reinstall from scratch all that is bash related
2. fix the current problem

Comment: Using `set -o vi` as an interactive command would not affect new shell sessions, so I assume that you added this (or something) to one of your shell's startup files. You don't show this file or mention what changes you made to it, so it's a bit difficult to say how to correct it.

Comment: I have tried to add this to my start up file (`~/.bashrc`) but removed it since then (also rebooted) - yet the problem is still there

Comment: If that was the _only_ modification you did, and if you undid it, you would not have an issue now, but you have, so you didn't.

Comment: If you did nothing as root, then it is a config file in your home directory. Try moving them out of the way (move then to a holding directory; better than deleting them, as it is reversible).

Comment: Check if you have a `.inputrc` in your home directory. Bash can react bizarrely to syntax errors there.

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you

Comment: What was the problem? If you found a solution, please write an answer.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' sounds like you caught it (see comment above). Want to post an answer?